# Make default value of a "Short[]" element 0 instead of null?

Tags: java

I have a program that creates lists and needs any assigned values to be 0.  Its been running fine when I do with `int[] humpty_dumpty = new int[20];`  but to optimize the size of the lists I set them to `Short[]` and now my program is breaking because it takes the zero's as inputs(and `Short[] humpty_dumpty = new Short[20];` is making the default value `null`).

Is there a way to set it to default zero without having to iterate through the entire list(I can do this via a for loop but was wondering if there was a way to make its behavior similar to int)?

Comment: This is the behavior of the language. There is no way to change it and have it still be Java. There are handy functions in [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), such as `Arrays.fill(Object[], Object)`, however.

Comment: In short, don't use an object when you really should be using a primitive. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between a `Short[]` and a `short[]`. Elements of the latter will be initialized to `0` because `short` is a "primitive" type and cannot be null. The capitalized `Short` class will be initialized to `null` because it is really just an `Object` wrapping a `short` value.

Answer (score 2):

You may create an array of primitive type instead of wrapper,

```
short []ar=new short[20];
```

Answer (score 1):

Short[] doesn't 'optimize the size of the lists' at all, and it has a default value of null. short[] does, and it has a default value of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Answers, in order:

1)  Requirement first, optimization last.  Don't use sparse arrays, or try to be 'smart', unless you specifically need to do this & deal with the extra code/ overhead.

2)  Use common *methods* (possibly in an Instance or Static Helper *class*) to avoid repeating common code.

eg.   short sparseGet (Short[] array, int i) {return (array[i] != null ? array[i] : 0);}

3)  Perhaps use short[] rather than Short[]?  Uppercase types are not primitives, but Value Wrapper classes -- and stored as object references (pointers) to instances, thus slower & more memory-intensive.

4)  Uppercase 'Value Wrapper' types *are* appropriate where you may have null values, from a database. eg.  Person.Age would ideally be Integer, if there's any possibility you/ the database might not have data for that field.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm a pretty new to Java but your advice is very helpful.